# Subdivision To Preserve Low Poly Style

Tags: mesh, vertices, faces

I'm working on a low poly style scene, meaning that individual triangles are intentionally visible.  I need to subdivide the scene while preserving the original geometry.

Basically, for every triangle I'd like to add 3 new vertices to create 4 triangles like this, so that it's still flat:

[image: example]

It may seem odd that I'm basically just increasing vertex count, but this is because I have a vertex shader that is warping the points, and I need more vertices for the effect to look nice.

I know about the 'poke face' but this does not work because I must reduce edge lengths for the effect.

Is there any built in tool I can use to accomplish my goal?
Thank you

Comment: W S (subdivide) should do this? 1 cut, 0 smoothness..

Comment: @RobinBetts that should be an answer

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I tried doing that, but it doesn't seem to correctly interpolate the UV map, or possibly the normals?  Every triangle is supposed to have the same normal and uv coordinate.

Comment: @Sazerac.. it's one of those.. seems too obvious a thing to have tried, therefore probably not an answer.. I'll have a closer look at it when I can..

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing the problem with UV's / Normals. Is there a sample you can share via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the **Edge Split Modifier**?
It does the trick for me.

This is an Ico-Sphere. I added the **Edge Split Modifier** to it, then I **sharpened all the edges** (or just the ones between which there should be no interpolation of normal values), then I **added Subdivisions** with **Mesh > Subdivide**, Slices set to 1 and Smoothness to 0, like suggested.

[image: Edge Split Modifier to keep Normals from being interpolated in Subdivision]

The UVs split as they should.
[image: UVs before Subdivision]

[image: Uvs after Subdivision]